# Azure Search - Promoting Older Data

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am creating an Azure Search scoring profile. In my data set, I have an `Edm.DateTimeOffset` field called `ExpiresOn`. I'm using this field to promote certain documents. To do that, I'm using the freshness function like this:

```
"name": "Aging",
"functions": [
  {
    "type": "freshness",
    "fieldName": "ExpiresOn",
    "boost": 10,
    "interpolation": "quadratic",
    "freshness": {
      "boostingDuration": "P14D"
    }
  },
}
```

From my understanding, this scoring profile will promote records that have an `ExpiresOn` value within the next 14 days. The "fresher" items will be given more relevance. My question is, what if I want to promote "staler" or "older" items. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To promote older items, you actually demote newer items. You can do this by providing a boost factor that is greater than zero, but less than one (0.5 for example). Details can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798928.aspx#Anchor_5).