# How to show Trending search key words in azure cognitive search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I wanted to display trending keywords (in search) to user...how to achieve this in **azure cognitive search**?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat a broad question. You can achieve this by including a [DateTimeOffset filed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types) in your documents, with a value coresponsing to the document "freshness". Then, create a [scoring profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-scoring-profiles) that boosts fresher documents so they would show higher in search requests.

Here are some similar questions posted in SO:

- [Azure Search - Promoting Older Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873572/azure-search-promoting-older-data)
- [Boosting docs based on date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680139/boosting-docs-based-on-date-range/49681562)